# Call SQL "function" (stored procedure?) every time a database column is selected

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am running MySQL 5.6. I have a number of various "name" columns in the database (in various tables). These get imported every year by each customer as a CSV data dump. There are a number of places that these names are displayed throughout this website. The issue is, the names have almost no formatting (and to this point, no sanitization existed upon importation):

```
Phil Eaton, PHIL EATON, Phil EATON, etc.
```

Thus, the website sometimes look like a mess when these names are involved. There are a number of ways that I can think to do this, but none that are particularly appealing.

First, I can have a filter in Javascript. However, as I said, these names exist in a number of places throughout this (large) site. I may end up missing a page. The names do not exist already within nice "name"-classed divs/spans, etc.

Second, I could filter in PHP (the backend). This seems about as effective as doing it in Javascript. I could do it on the API, but there was still not a central method for pulling names from the database. So I could still miss an API call anyway.

Finally, the obvious "best" way is to sanitize the existing data in place for each name column. Then at the same time, immediately start sanitizing all names that get imported each time we add a customer. The issue with the first part of this is that there are hundreds of millions of rows of names in the database. Updating these could take a long amount of time and be disruptive to the clients' daily routines.

So, the most appealing way to correct this in the short-term is to invoke a function every time a column is selected. In this way I could "decorate" every name column with a formatting function so the names will appear uniform on the frontend. So ultimately, my question is: is it possible to invoke a specific function in SQL to format each row every time a specific column is selected? In other words, maybe can I call a stored procedure every time a column is selected? (Point being, I'm trying to keep the formatting in SQL to avoid the propagation of usage.)

Comment: in client-side code? You'd already know what fields are being selected anyways, so there's no point in "automating" this. DB-side, you could try a trigger, but a view might be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, I was being ambiguous. No. I want to do the formatting in SQL if I can. I want to be able to call a format "function" (or perhaps a stored procedure) in SQL every time a column is selected. The least number of usages of these columns are in the actual DB itself. As I said, each column is used in many places on the actual site. I don't want to do this client-side because the number of times a column is used on the website only grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can't trigger something on SELECT, but I have an idea (it's only an idea, now I don't have time to try it, sorry).

You probably can create a VIEW on this table, with the same structure, but with the stored procedure applied to the names fields, and select from this view in your PHP.

But it has two backdraw:

1. You have to modify all your SELECT statements in your PHPs.
2. The server will always call that procedure. Maybe you can store the formatted values, then check for it (cache them).

On the other hand I agree with HLGEM, I also suggest to format the data on import, because it's a very bad practice to import something you don't check into a DB (SQL Injections?). The batch tasking is also a good idea to clean up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

I presume names are called frequently so invoking a sanitization function every time they are called could severely slow down your system. Further, you can't just do a simple setting to get this, you would have to change every buit of SQL code that is run that includes names.

Personally how I would handle it is to fix the imports so they put in a sanitized version for new names. It is a bad idea to directly put any data into a database without some sort of staging and clean up.

Then I would tackle the old names and fix them in batches in a nightly run that is scheduled when the fewest people are using the system. You would have to do some testing on dev to determine how big a batch you could run without interfering with other things the database is doing. The alrger the batch the sooner you would get through all the names, but even though this will take time, it is the surest method of getting the data cleaned up and over time the data will appear better to the users. If the design of your datbase allows you to identify which are the more active names (such as an is_active flag for a customer or am order in the last year), I would prioritize the update by that. Alternatively, you could clean up one client at a time starting with whichever one has noticed the problem and is driving this change.

Comment: Sorry, I admit that my original question was a bit of a ramble. But I did include this solution in my 5th paragraph (except for batches and your confirmation). Although I am grateful for your confirmation of my "best solution", I am not sure how this answers my actual question.

Comment: I added the batches becasue that was s olution you had not mentioned. The first paragraph answers your question,.. It is possible but it woudl take a massive maintenance effort to find every piece of code that you have that would refernce the name column as each woudl have to be changed individually..

Comment: Right, which is why I would like to make these formatting changes at the database level in the short-term. There may only be 5 columns of names in the database. But there could be hundreds of places these names are used on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers before give some possible solutions. But, the short answer for the specific option you are asking is : No. There is no such thing called a 
"Select Statement Trigger", that too for a single column, although triggers come close for this kind of expectation, but only for Insert, Update and Delete operations.